# jQuery's noConflict() code doesn't make sense

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand source code of noConflict function. It is in **jQuery 3.3.1**:

```
jQuery.noConflict = function( deep ) {
  if ( window.$ === jQuery ) {
    window.$ = _$;
  }
  if ( deep && window.jQuery === jQuery ) {
    window.jQuery = _jQuery;
  }
  return jQuery;
};
```

Why they check for strict equality between window.jQuery and jQuery? `(deep && window.jQuery === jQuery)`

How can `window.jQuery` contain anything, besides jQuery?

`window.jQuery` can be equal to jQuery, can be undefined I guess, but nothing else. Other libraries don't put jQuery to window object, I think.
And then, there is this code from "Professional jQuery" (book):

```
noConflict: function( deep ) {
     window.$ = _$;
     if ( deep ) {
        window.jQuery = _jQuery;
     }
     return jQuery;
}
```

which doesn't use `window.jQuery === jQuery.`

Comment: window.jQuery might already be defined by another version of jQuery or such in case you need to run more than one version in parallel.

Comment: But, in that case, we can pass true to noConfilct, like this noConfilct(true), and that would be enough to overwrite window.jQuery with previous value. No need for window.jQuery === jQuery.

Comment: No, if you pass `true` and `window.jQuery` (let's assume version 2) is **not** equal to `jQuery` (let's assume version 3) then you wouldn't overwrite it. This is because you might have loaded jQuery2 first and then load jQuery3 and call `.noConflict` on it. The problem becomes apparent if you have even more versions load jQuery 1, 2, and 3 then if you call `.noConflict` on one, you don't necessarily want it to restore the previous value, as it depends on the order they were loaded in.

Comment: Would it not be smarter for you to ask this dirrectly on https://github.com/jquery/jquery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in case of multiple versions of jQuery being loaded. Let's make a sample here

```js
function PseudoJQuery(version) {
  //keep track of version
  this.version = version;

  //keep previous $ and jQuery values
  var _$ = window.$;
  var _jQuery = window.jQuery;

  //assign the current version
  var jQuery = this;
  window.$ = jQuery;
  window.jQuery = jQuery;

  //re-use the jQuery.noConflict
  this.noConflict = function(deep) {
    if (window.$ === jQuery) {
      window.$ = _$;
    }
    //remove the check
    if (deep /*&& window.jQuery === jQuery */) {
      window.jQuery = _jQuery;
    }
    return jQuery;
  };
}

//load multiple versions of our jQuery
var j2 = new PseudoJQuery(2);
var j3 = new PseudoJQuery(3);

console.log("version after loading", window.jQuery.version);

j2.noConflict(true);

console.log("version after noConflict", window.jQuery.version); //error
```

So, this a simplified version of what jQuery does when initialising and what it tries to restore when calling `noConflict`. This *fails* because when we call `j2.noConflict`, the `window.jQuery` variable would be returned to its initial state - `undefined`, thus destroying the version 3 installation.

With the check in place, the *current* version of jQuery will only destroy itself on calling `noConflict` but not any other jQuery installation.

```js
function PseudoJQuery(version) {
  //keep track of version
  this.version = version;

  //keep previous $ and jQuery values
  var _$ = window.$;
  var _jQuery = window.jQuery;

  //assign the current version
  var jQuery = this;
  window.$ = jQuery;
  window.jQuery = jQuery;

  //re-use the jQuery.noConflict
  this.noConflict = function(deep) {
    if (window.$ === jQuery) {
      window.$ = _$;
    }

    if (deep && window.jQuery === jQuery) {
      window.jQuery = _jQuery;
    }
    return jQuery;
  };
}

//load multiple versions of our jQuery
var j2 = new PseudoJQuery(2);
var j3 = new PseudoJQuery(3);

console.log("version after loading", window.jQuery.version);

j2.noConflict(true);

console.log("version after noConflict", window.jQuery.version);
```

Comment: So, `_jQuery` retains its value even after `PseudoJQuery(2)` call? This is closure mechanism? If `_jQuery` was, say `3`, after `PseudoJQuery(2)` call, it would still be `3`?

Comment: Yes, `_jQuery` is only visible within the closure, so it wouldn't get changed after the initialisation. And each instance of `PseudoJQuery` has its own copy of `_jQuery`. For "version 2", `_jQuery` holds `undefined` because there was nothing assigned to `window.jQuery` before. For "version 3", `_jQuery` holds a reference to "version 2". When you make version 2 restore the value it does `window.jQuery = undefined` even though it shouldn't.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but if we load jQuery_v1 and then jQuery_v2, and call `jQuery.noConflict()`, it will fire up jQuery_v2's `noConflict`?

Comment: @Darko yes, that's correct but you might still have a reference to a previously loaded version of jQuery, for example, if you dynamically load the libraries. So you'd load v2, grab a reference to it, load v3 and then use the reference to v2 to call `.noConflict()`. It's a bit of an edge case but it still shouldn't break jQuery on the page. One example how this might happen is if you queue up some async code and aren't sure when exactly would each execute.

Comment: In `window.jQuery === jQuery`, `window.jQuery` will hold most recent value, and not a value at the time of `PseudoJQuery()` execution. And `jQuery` is private value, existing only in `PseudoJQuery()`. And that value is retained even after `PseudoJQuery()` stops executing. Just correct me if I'm wrong and I have no more questions.

Comment: @Darko yes, `window.jQuery` is a *single* value for everything, because it's a global. So it will only hold one version of jQuery - without calling `.noConflict` it will be the last one that was loaded. The `var jQuery` variable exists for each *instance* of PseudoJQuery. When you call `.noConfluct()` that method only has access to its own `jQuery` variable and since it's not exposed, nothing outside can change it.